# why to PyTorch sparse tensor resize_ cannot work?

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix

Working with a large matrices and I want to save memory so I use the following code to avoid dense format and large memory usage. but I cann't use the in-place resize with the sparse format.

It give me the following error

> NotImplementedError: Could not run 'aten::resize_' with arguments from the 'SparseCPU' backend.

, Appreciate your help so that I can dio the in-place resize_ with sparse format. Also if you can give me a hints on the normal tensor (in sparse format comparing to non sparse format) operations efficiency from your experience as I'm new(very fresh :) ) to pytorch.

```
K1 = -mmread('full1_0.1.A').tocoo()  
K1_norm = linalg.norm(K1)
values = K1.data
indices = numpy.vstack((K1.row, K1.col))
i = torch.LongTensor(indices)
v = torch.FloatTensor(values)
shape = K1.shape

K1=torch.sparse.FloatTensor(i, v, torch.Size(shape))
K1=K1.resize_(1,2285031204)
```

Comment: Just a curiosity, what's the shape of the sparse `K1`?  Why do you need to `resize` it?  I'm familiar with the `scipy.sparse`, but not the `pytorch` version.  The `scipy.sparse` objects are not subclasses on `numpy.ndarray`, and don't have the same functionality.  Even `reshape` is limited.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the size of the original matrix is 47802x47802 ,so I want to vectorize for further application, the matrix is sparse it has only around 3millions non zero elements and I want to take advantage of that. The matrix is a result of nonlinear thermo-mechanical simulation and I'm using it in further applications.

Comment: So it's a `reshape` you want?

Comment: any function that can do the reshape but witout coping the data. All IN-PLACE. and can be applied to the sparse format.

Comment: I want to add that I want to use pytorch instead of scipy because the operations I use will add one more dim in each operation. so maybe I will have at the end 3d tensor.